# how to make the view controller compatible with iphone 5 if xib not taken

Tags: iphone, xib

How can a view controller be make compatible with iphone 5 if it's xib file not taken. Is it possible to make that change programmatically. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What does “if it's xib file not taken” mean?

Comment: @IronManGill  added view controllers class without xib files i did things only programmatically only.

Comment: yes he said things in other way but its not like we cant understand what he ment

Comment: @PrakashDesai In my iphone5 it is showing dead space at bottom it means that screen size is 480 only then these methods can not be implemented?

Comment: the size of view is 480 means it is for iphone classic for solving this do if else as i have suggested in my answer. Your view height is 480 but iphone 5 height is more than 550 so its obvious you will get dead space hope now its clear :)

Comment: @PrakashDesai that i know, but i am asking for that solution.

Comment: that is the solution @Iphone if height is more than 480 change code in way that fits iphone 5 change frame size and else change frame size which fits iphone classic. you need to do code twice is it not solution? do you understand now? tell me if any confusion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes defiantly you can do this. XIB are just files too just open one in a texteditor - you'll see that it consists of readable xml code. now for making viewController compatible with Iphone 5 just put if else condition and make thing separately for different devices by checking height of particular device
but defiantly its going to be long job

For my universal app, Forex App, I'm simply using the screen height detection concept like so:

```
CGSize screenSize = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size;

if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) {
    if (screenSize.height > 480.0f) {
        /*Do iPhone 5 stuff here.*/
    } else {
        /*Do iPhone Classic stuff here.*/
    }
} else {
    /*Do iPad stuff here.*/
}
```

Answer (score 0):

check the device is iPhone 5 or not and set frame programmatic..

```
CGRect screenRect = [[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame];

    if (screenRect.size.height >= 548 )
    {
       // set your frame for iPhone 5
    }else
    {
       // set your frame for iPhone 4
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do that by adding the following condition

```
CGSize result = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size;
if(result.height == 480)
{
    iPhone 4 or less 
}
else if (result.height == 568)
{
     iPhone 5 condition
}
```

Wherever you want to differentiate between the two phones.